# Is it possible to connect two Azure VNets using site-to-site (VPN) connection?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

According Azure document, site-to-site(VPN) connection is used to connect Azure VNet to an on-prem network, VNet-to-VNet connection is used to connect two Azure VNets, I wonder if it is possible to connect two Azure VNets using site-to-site(VPN) connection?

The reason we want this is that we need to support the ability for customer to connect their network to our Azure VNet, if the above option is possible we just need to support site-to-site(VPN), otherwise, we'll have to support both connection type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal

Comment: if both vnets you want to connect are azure virtual networks, an easier approach would be azure vnet peering : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-deployment-models-subscriptions

Comment: Peering across tenants requires to manually accept the invitation from customer. We want to avoid this manual step.

Comment: Thats how vnet connections work anyway. whether it is peering or site/site.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. [You can connect 2 Azure VNETS using a S2S VPN, VNET to VNET connection (which is just a azure managed S2S VPN), or VNET Peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal#about-connecting-vnets). It is a best practice to use VNET to VNET connections for Azure VNETs, and then S2S for other connections.

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Its possible to Connect to Vnets using S2S VPN connection.

You could make a S2S connection between 2 Vnets with 2 VPN gateways or deploy a VPN software device in one Vnet and VPN gateway in another.

**Reference:**

[Connect Vnet to Vnet usins S2S VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal)

[About Highly Available gateway configurations - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-highlyavailable)